# Escalation of exceptions in akka actors and futures in scala

Tags: scala, exception, akka, future, spray

I am developing a server which is an intermediate server between 2 other endpoints.
So I implement a spray route which triggers a computation, and this computation invokes an actor which invokes a spray client.
The following pattern applies:

Client => ...=> (Spray Route => Service Actor => Spray Client) =>... => distant Server.
I am developing the exception management and I have a hard time understanding what to do.
When the distant server sends me BadRequest, or any error code, I want to throw an exception, which leads answering to the client the same kind of errors.

I guess my question is general about exception handling and excalation.

I naively believed that when I throw an exception in a future, the future could call the case Failure:

```
    def receive = {
      case SendRequest => {
           val s = sender()
           val call = for { 
              request <- ComputeRequest
              result <- CallSprayClient ? request
           } yield result

           call onComplete {
             case Success(succ) => s ! succ
             case Failure(e) = throw e
           }
       }
    }
```

The thing is, when ComputeRequest or CallSprayClient throw an exception, the Failure case of my callback is not triggered.
I looked at the supervision pattern, but it seems that the exception or message causing the error is not propagated neither.
In my particular case, depending on the exception, I would like to send a different http response to my client, hence the need to escalate.

What development pattern should I apply?

Thanks.

Comment: One main point is probably what happens with the exception you throw at this line: `case Failure(e) = throw e`. This will run on an ExecutionContext thread and will never bubble up to your code. So, if you need to *handle* the exception you cannot rely on just throwing it.

Comment: You don't show how `ComputeRequest` is implemented. If the method itself throws an error before the future is even created it won't be propagated in the future (obviously). If the exception occurs during the future processing itself it will be propagated. To handle such an exception with spray-routing, you just complete with a `Future` and then provide an ExceptionHandler to decide how to deal with the exception.

Comment: So, you should focus on answering the basic question where the exception occurs exactly and maybe post a more standalone example if you cannot explain why things are propagated the way they are.

Comment: the for-comprehension IS a future. ComputeRequest returns a future, and CallSprayClient as well.  The exception can happened in both "sub futures".  The basic answers are there.

Comment: A couple of things.  Ask (`?`) will not propagate an exception unless the receiving actor does so explicitly (via `Status.Failure`).  So your ask call to `CallSprayClient` probably is not behaving the way you expect in terms of failures in that actor itself.  If `result` itself can be inspected to see if the call was a failure then you can `flatMap` into a failure if necessary.  Lastly, `Future` callbacks in an actor (like your `onComplete`) do not execute in the context of the actor, so throwing an exception there will not trigger the supervisor.

Comment: Thanks.  So if I want things to be propagated, I should not use throw but rather send back Status.Failure.  Thanks !

Comment: That's one approach.  Another is to return a type of result that can be inspected by the caller and turned into a failure if necessary.  The former approach is ok if ask is always being used.  The latter is more flexible and works regardless of ask vs tell.